# How to detect if Windows supports running x64 processes?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

Starting in December 2020, [Windows supports x64 emulation on ARM64 devices](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2020/12/10/introducing-x64-emulation-in-preview-for-windows-10-on-arm-pcs-to-the-windows-insider-program/). How can a program determine if the current version of Windows supports running x64 applications?

Prior to x64 emulation on ARM64, we could use `RuntimeInformation.OSArchitecture == Architecture.X64` for this.

Comment: This is not a window issue. It is an issue if your apps support x64.  Many apps have multiple versions (x86,x32,x64).  Depending on what version of app you installed will determine version.   The reason for vendor supplying multiple version is the app has to work with other apps that may not support all the versions.

Comment: Since this is tagged with .net, why do you care about emulation? The jitter should compile to arm directly.

Comment: The software in question has to run "natively" as all supported architectures to be able to set global CBTHooks, which requires me to compile it for all the architectures on the machine. The question goes to how we can detect which process architectures can be run on the machine.

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wow64apiset/nf-wow64apiset-iswow64process2 ?

Comment: @SimonMourier Not really. That checks if a specific running process is ARM64/x64/x86. What I am looking for is a way to determine if the system is capable of executing x64, or ARM64, or x86.

Comment: Have you read the link in detail?

Comment: I have and I didn't find anything in this API that would allow you to query whether the system can emulate non-native ISAs. It's taking a process handle as the first argument. That doesn't suggest that it were querying a system property.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GetMachineTypeAttributes` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getmachinetypeattributes) to check if Windows supports running x64 code.

For example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Program
{
    [Flags]
    enum MachineAttributes
    {
        None = 0,
        UserEnabled = 0x00000001,
        KernelEnabled = 0x00000002,
        Wow64Container = 0x00000004,
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
    static extern MachineAttributes GetMachineTypeAttributes(ushort WowGuestMachine);
    const ushort IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64 = 0x8664;
    const ushort IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386 = 0x014c;
    const ushort IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_ARM64 = 0xAA64;

    public static void Main()
    {
        var x64Support = GetMachineTypeAttributes(IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64);
        Console.WriteLine("x64 support: {0}", x64Support);
        var x86Support = GetMachineTypeAttributes(IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386);
        Console.WriteLine("x86 support: {0}", x86Support);
        var arm64Support = GetMachineTypeAttributes(IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_ARM64);
        Console.WriteLine("Arm64 support: {0}", arm64Support);

    }
}
```

Running this on an x64 device produces:

```
x64 support: UserEnabled, KernelEnabled
x86 support: UserEnabled, Wow64Container
Arm64 support: None
```

And on an Arm64 Win11 device produces:

```
x64 support: UserEnabled
x86 support: UserEnabled, Wow64Container
Arm64 support: UserEnabled, KernelEnabled
```

So to detect if x64 code can be run, check if the returned value is not `MachineAttributes.None`:

```cs
public static bool SupportsX64()
{
    return GetMachineTypeAttributes(IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64) != MachineAttributes.None;
}
```

**Updated**

Looks like `GetMachineTypeAttributes` was added in Win11, so if attempting to P/Invoke it throws `EntryPointNotFoundException` then you know that you're running on pre-Win11 and can use your older detection logic:

```cs
public static bool SupportsX64()
{
    try
    {
        // Win11+: Ask the OS if we can run AMD64 code.
        return GetMachineTypeAttributes(IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64) != MachineAttributes.None;
    }
    catch (EntryPointNotFoundException)
    {
        // Pre-Win11: Only x64 machines can run x64 code.
        return RuntimeInformation.OSArchitecture == Architecture.X64;
    }
}
```