# Can Inno Setup detect Windows11 on ARM64 hardware which can emulate x64?

Tags: inno-setup, emulation, arm64, windows-11

Windows 11 supports emulating x64 hardware whilst actually running on an ARM64 platform. An example of this would be running Windows inside a virtual machine on a Mac.

Previously my Inno installer was just using the following to ensure that the PC was capable of running our software:

```
ArchitecturesAllowed=x64
```

However on an ARM-based system like the example given this causes the setup to terminate because it (rightly) sees `arm64` as the architecture.

I can't just add `arm64` to that line because that won't distinguish between older ARM-based systems which have no x64 emulation capability and those that do.

Hopefully, in the [Inno Setup Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/innosetup/c/_k3ddQ2CV8E/m/YRH34SKDBQAJ) this topic was discussed as follows:

> Jordan Russell Oct 4, 2021, 5:45:40 PM
>
> ...
>
> If they were to switch to "ArchitecturesInstall64BitMode=x64 arm64",
> then you should get the x64 files. Unfortunately, however, the x64
> files would also be installed on older ARM64 builds that don't support
> x64 emulation, resulting in a non-functioning app.
>
> ...
>
> I do still plan, though, to add official support for detecting x64
> emulation in the near future. A new architecture identifier
> "x64compatible" will match both x64 Windows and ARM64 Windows with x64
> emulation support, and an IsX64Compatible function will also be added.
> To encourage adoption of "x64compatible" so that more x64 apps can be
> installed on ARM64, the existing "x64" will be deprecated and renamed
> to "x64strict", and later on the compiler will print a warning when
> "x64" is used.

However the relevant Inno documentation sections don't seem to have any mention of this. (https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_architecturesallowed,
https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_isarm64)

Is there any built-in way to do it?

If not I may have to try some direct system calls such as those mentioned in [How to detect if Windows supports running x64 processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68557282/how-to-detect-if-windows-supports-running-x64-processes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the question you have linked shows, you can call [`GetMachineTypeAttributes` WinAPI function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getmachinetypeattributes) on Windows 11 to determine x64 support. On older versions of Windows, use [`ProcessorArchitecture` Inno Setup support function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_processorarchitecture)

Something like this should do (but I do not have ARM64 machine to test this on).

```pascal
[Code]

const
  IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64 = $8664;

function GetMachineTypeAttributes(
    Machine: Word; var MachineTypeAttributes: Integer): HRESULT;
  external 'GetMachineTypeAttributes@Kernel32.dll stdcall delayload';

<event('InitializeSetup')>
function InitializeSetupCheckArchitecture(): Boolean;
var
  MachineTypeAttributes: Integer;
  Arch: TSetupProcessorArchitecture;
begin
  if IsWindows11OrNewer then
  begin
    OleCheck(
      GetMachineTypeAttributes(IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64, MachineTypeAttributes));
    if MachineTypeAttributes <> 0 then
    begin
      Log('Windows 11 or newer, with x64 support');
      Result := True;
    end
      else
    begin
      Log('Windows 11 or newer, without x64 support');
      Result := False;
    end;
  end
    else
  begin
    Arch := ProcessorArchitecture;
    if Arch = paX64 then
    begin
      Log('Windows 10 or older, on x64 architecture');
      Result := True;
    end
      else
    begin
      Log('Windows 10 or older, not on x64 architecture');
      Result := False;
    end;
  end;

  if not Result then
  begin
    MsgBox('This product can be installed on system with x64 support only.',
      mbError, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

The code completely replaces the `ArchitecturesAllowed` directive (it assumes it is not set, though setting it to `x64 arm64` should do no harm).

The `IsWindows11OrNewer` comes from [Determine Windows version in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5849917/850848).

Comment: Thanks so much Martin. I don't actually have an ARM64 machine either but one of my customer's does; I plan to coordinate with them to test this & I'll update here when I can.